# how can i hide a tab on the tab bar in iphone

Tags: uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

i'm working on an iphone project and i have to show a login view and after log in i have to show a tab bar, all the tabs show different views and all the views have controls that link to other views. so i was wondering what can i do about it, first i was thinking to work with a navigation controller but while reading some posts they suggest not to work with a navigation that includes a tab bar controller. so, i think i can work with a tab bar controller and the first tab should be the login tab but i need to hide the tab bar from the view while logging in and after that i can show the tab bar with the other tabs. i don't know if it's possible. that's why i need your help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to set the property "`hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`" to YES. like..

```
mTSProjVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed =YES;
```

Comment: will this property just hide the login tab bar item?